# Why do removed packages still appear in dpkg?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, uninstall

I wanted to uninstall the package `pure-ftpd` (because I finally set up sftp to replace it), so I ran the command:

```
sudo apt remove pure-ftpd
sudo apt autoremove
```

However, dpkg still lists it. (I later ran `sudo apt purge pure-ftpd` which may have made things worse)

```
$ dpkg -l pure*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name             Version      Architecture Description
+++-================-============-============-===================================
un  pure-ftpd        <none>       <none>       (no description available)
rc  pure-ftpd-common 1.0.47-3     all          Pure-FTPd FTP server (Common Files)
```

Why is that, and how do I properly/completely remove a package from my system? Preferably using `apt`, but if that's not possible I'd like to also know why.

Note that this is a raspberry pi running raspbian, but I don't think that makes any difference for this question.

Comment: Your are looking at dpkg's database of *all known packages from all known sources*, both installed and uninstalled. Your NOT looking at a dynamic list of what's installed right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have removed the package as seen by `un` or `rc` in the first column of `dpkg`'s output.

- u - unknown
- n - not installed
- r - removed
- c - only config files installed/remaining on the system

As for your question, the package might still be referenced somewhere in `/var/lib/dpkg/status` and/or `/var/lib/dpkg/available`

Comment: So basically it's removed and I shouldn't worry about it?

Comment: Basically, yes. `dpkg` is showing this just as some sort of reference. So nothing to be worried about.